# Parentheses affecting query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am confused by the results of a query I am running. Hopefully this doesn't end with me slapping my head and feeling like an idiot, but here goes (SQL Server 2008).

First query was this:

```
SELECT p.product_number,p.long_desc
FROM products p
WHERE p.prod_status = 1
AND ((p.long_desc IS NULL) OR (p.long_desc LIKE '%N/A%'))
ORDER BY p.product_number
```

Second version is this:

```
 SELECT p.product_number,p.long_desc
 FROM products p
 WHERE p.prod_status = 1
 AND p.long_desc IS NULL 
 OR p.long_desc LIKE '%N/A%'
 ORDER BY p.product_number
```

There are three products in the second version that do not appear in the first, yet to me these two queries should give identical results. The three items that appear in the second but not the first all have the value `N/A` in the `long_desc` column.

However there are many others with `N/A` as well and show up in both versions.

What don't I understand about the use of parenthesis here?

Comment: Here's a link you may find useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186992(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AND` has a higher precedence than `OR` (see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx)), so without the parentheses, the query is equivalent to this:

```
 SELECT p.product_number,p.long_desc
 FROM products p
 WHERE (p.prod_status = 1
 AND p.long_desc IS NULL) 
 OR p.long_desc LIKE '%N/A%'
 ORDER BY p.product_number
```